# Let $α$ and $β$ be the roots of equation $px^2+qx+r=0,p≠0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots

Let $α$ and $β$ be the roots of equation $px^2+qx+r=0,p≠0$, If $p,q,r$ are in A.P and  $\dfrac{1}{α}+\dfrac{1}{β}=4$, then the value of $|α−β|$ is $:$

1. $\dfrac{\sqrt{61}}{9} $
2. $\dfrac{2\sqrt{17}}{9}$
3. $\dfrac{\sqrt{34}}{9}$
4. $\dfrac{2\sqrt{13}}{9}$

---

$\text{Somewhere it explained as:}$

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=4$$

$$2q = p + r$$

$$\Rightarrow \space\space-2(\alpha+\beta)=1+\alpha\beta$$

> $$\Rightarrow-2\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}+1\cdots(1)$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}=-9$$

$\text{Equation having roots $α$ and $β$ is:}$    $$9x^2\space +\space 4x\space -1=0$$

$$\alpha,\space \beta=\frac{-4\underline{+}\sqrt{16+36}}{2\times 9}$$

$$\left|\alpha-\beta\right|=\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{9}$$

> $\text{As I know:} $$$x^2-(\alpha+\beta)+(\alpha\times\beta)=0\cdots(2)$$

$\text{My question is:}$

> Can you explain in formal/alternative way, please?

Comment: Is there any step you did not understand, or do you want a shorter proof?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, I updated post, equation $(1)$, unable to understand and also how he came with final equation, according to me, it should be as equation $(2)$. Thanks. I need little bit clarification and and another/shorter solution if possible.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay, It's given in the problem statement that $p,q,r$ are in AP, so we have $2q=p+r$. As $q=-(\alpha+\beta)$ and $r=\alpha\beta$, we get the equation before equation $(1)$. Dividing both sides by $\alpha\beta$ gives equation $(1)$.

Comment: @learner, yes, you are correct, that I'd missed. Thanks.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay, After obtaining that $\alpha\beta=-\frac 19$, there's actually a simpler way to obtain the value of $|\alpha-\beta|$ without explicitly computing the roots. Use the following identity keeping in mind that $|x|$ is always non-negative:$$|\alpha+\beta|^2-|\alpha-\beta|^2=4\alpha\beta$$

Comment: Was this asked in JEE?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, yes.

Comment: Ah, I see. JEE asks very similar questions to this. There's always some trick, you should know all these funny identities by heart, even for physics and chemistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. By the usual formula, the difference of the roots is $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$. Hence it's enough for us to find the correct $a,b,c$ for which the roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

But here's the trick: So we know that $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} = 4$. That means that if we look at the equation $2q = p + r$, we get that $\frac{1}{\alpha \beta} = -9$. So if $ex^2+fx+g=0$is the equation satisfied by $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\frac{1}{\beta}$, then $e=1$, $f$ is the negative of the sum which is $-4$, and $g$ is the product, which is $-9$. Putting together, this gives us $x^2-4x-9=0$ is the equation satisfied by $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\frac{1}{\beta}$. To get the equation satisfied by $\alpha$ and $\beta$, all we do is invert the $x$ by making it $\frac{1}{x}$, and then that gives us $9x^2+4x-1=0$. Finally, using the formula we know above of the difference of the roots, we get the answer as $\frac{2 \sqrt{13}}{9}$.

Comment: Is typo $2q=p+r$ and $ex^2+fx+g=0$?

Comment: Must be. Please correct it.